# Invalid argument supplied

Tags: php, codeigniter, foreach

In following code i has error in view, how can fix it?

My data in table is as:

[image]

CI_Controller:

```
    $update = array('15'); // this is a example from my $_POST that are array.
    if (is_array($update) && count($update) > 0) {
        foreach($update as $val){
            $data['query_hi'] = $this->db->get_where('hotel_image', array('relation' => $val))->row();
        }
        $this -> load -> view('admin/residence_update', $data);
    }
```

View:

```
                        foreach($query_hi->images as $val){
                            echo $val;
                        }
```

Error:

> A PHP Error was encountered
>
> Severity: Warning
>
> Message: Invalid argument supplied for foreach()
>
> Filename: core/Loader.php(679) : eval()'d code
>
> Line Number: 279

Comment: Do a `var_dump($data['query_hi']);` before you load the view and add the output to your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that it returns only one result for your query... and the array is overridden at each cycle. Try this:

```
$update = array('15'); // this is a example from my $_POST that are array.
if (is_array($update) && count($update) > 0) {
    $data= array();
    foreach($update as $val){
        $tmp= $this->db->get_where('hotel_image', array('relation' => $val));
        foreach($tmp->result() as $row){
            $data['query_hi'][] = $row; 
        }
    }
    $this -> load -> view('admin/residence_update', $data);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you should try:

```
for($i=0;$i<count($query_hi);$i++)
{
  echo $query_hi[$i]->images;
}
```